# Add style attribute using javascript on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a inline-style using JavaScript as soon as the site is loaded (can't use CSS directly due to reasons). I want all text within a table to be horizontally centered,

This is my JavaScript code so far:

```
window.onload = center_content();
function center_content (){
    var all_td = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    all_td[0].style.textAlign = "center !important";
}
```

Edit: Code corrected so far

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GinSan/h46mz6na/4/ (remember that I can't directly use CSS in this case)

Any help is much appreciated. No jQuery solutions please.

Comment: `all_td[0].style.text-align = "center !important";` is interpreted as `all_td[0].style.text - align = "center !important";`, i.e. it tries to subtract `align` from `all_td[0].style.text`. Then you are trying to assign a value to that value, which doesn't make sense to the engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyphen-separated [properties of *style* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) should be used in **camelCase** when it comes to JavaScript.

Try using so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.textAlign = "center";
```

You could also use `.style["text-align"]` to achieve the same result.

However if you want to set the *priority* (i.e. `!important` keyword), not only the value, you could use [`.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) method as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/nowigo/1/edit)**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.setProperty("text-align", "center", "important");
```

---

And one more thing, by using `()` at `window.onload = center_content();` you're executing `center_content()` immediately and assigning the returned value which is `undefined` to `window.onload`.

You could either do it like `window.onload = center_content;` or use an anonymous function:

```
window.onload = function () { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: *"Hyphen-separated properties should be used in camelCase when it comes to JavaScript."* But note that that only works for the properties of the `element.style` object. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

Comment: @FelixKling Of course! I meant the style properties. I just forgot to mention it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, firefox doesn't show the error message anymore. However, the text still doesnt appear centered °v° Maybe there's another error somewhere, I added a fiddle

Comment: @Gin-San Your fiddle gives me a 404 error. I added mine. Check the update please.

Comment: Sorry, don't know why the link didn't work anymore. Tried your example, but for some reason, it doesn't work, don't know why :/ I added a functional fiddle link, could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Gin-San Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/h46mz6na/5/ I've used [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) method to select all `th` and `td` elements; Its [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `-` in a variable name or property. Instead use `style.textAlign`

Comment: You can use `-` in a property (name). You just can't use dot notation to access that property.